# Importing .R dependencies at the main.R at the azure batch

Tags: r, azure, cloud, azure-batch

I'm trying to run my main.R code at the azure batch.
I put the main.R in the blob storage. The problem is that the main.R needs to import other .R files which I put them at same container at blob storage. Now I want to import it at main.R to be used in the code.
I know for local usage you simply import them by :
source('/filepath/dependencies.R')

but I don't how to do it in my main.R that it gets it form the blob.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to place all of your R files in the same container and specify a resource file that references the container. This will direct Azure Batch compute nodes to download all of the files in the container as part of the task into the task working directory. Please see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/resource-files).

Alternatively you can explore using [Application Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-application-packages).